# SharePoint 2013 list show version history

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

i'm looking for a way to make the showing SharePoint 2013 list item version history more intuitive, and eventually i have found the JS code below; however, when i added the code to a SP 2013 list, it is not working. Please kindly advise how to implement the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var listItem;
var list;
var title;
var clientContext;
var item1;
var value;
var source;
var weburl;
var currentListGUID;

function getSetListItem()
{
    source=document.URL;
    clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    if (clientContext != undefined && clientContext != null)
    {
        weburl=_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;
        currentListGUID = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
        if(currentListGUID === "undefined" || currentListGUID === null)
        {
            alert('Please select one row');
        }
        else{
            var webSite = clientContext.get_web();
            var ctx = GetCurrentCtx();
            title =ctx.ListTitle;
            list = webSite.get_lists().getByTitle(title);
            var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(clientContext);
            if(Object.keys(selectedItems).length>1)
            {alert('Please select only one row');}
            else{
                for (var item in selectedItems)
                {
                    item1=selectedItems[item].id;
                }
                listItem = list.getItemById(item1);
                clientContext.load(this.listItem);
                clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnLoadSuccess),
                Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnLoadFailed));
                ShowDialog();
            }
        }
    }
}

function OnLoadSuccess(sender, args)
{
    value = this.listItem.get_item("FileLeafRef");
}

function ShowDialog()
{
    var options =
    {
        autoSize: true,
        allowMaximize: true,
        title: 'Version History',
        showClose: true,
        url:weburl+'_layouts/15/Versions.aspx?list=' + currentListGUID + '&ID='+item1+'&Source='+weburl+'/Lists/'+title+'/AllItems.aspx',
    };
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}
</script> 

<input id="btnGetSetListItem" onclick="getSetListItem()" type="button" value="Version History" />
```

Comment: Did you add this script to a content editor web part or to a script editor web part? If you look at your browser's console, there must be some JS errors showing up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with URL parameter in ShowDialog()
it should be  `url:weburl+'/_layouts/15/Versions.aspx....`
you have missed the slash before `_layouts/`

the weburl is a server relative URL ending without **'/'** you have to add it while making up dialog URL

Comment: Hi Akshay, I will appreciate it very much if you can help me on one more issue. I inserted the list viewer webpart to a publishing page, and then added the JS code.  The code is working fine when I saved or even checked-in the page, but it is no longer working when I published the page. The issue is that, even when I selected an item, but got the message saying "Please select one row" when I pushed the button, as if I didn't select any items.